# How many number of pairing devices on BlueZ?

Tags: bluez, pairing

How many pairing devices are on BlueZ?
I trace code, default pairing devices are unlimited, right?

On main.conf

```
# Maximum number of controllers allowed to be exposed to the system.
# Default=0 (unlimited)
# MaxControllers=0
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to the BlueZ source code, `MaxControllers`, initializes to 65535 (`UINT16_MAX`) by default. However, the actual number may be lower depending on the distro, going as low as 100.

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/src/main.c#n1015

If you are inquiring about max connections this number is much smaller, going as low as 7 concurrent connections (*check your manufacturer's documentation if available*).